# Transform object by removing a property but maintaining its content

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I'm trying to find a method to "reduce" an object.
This is what i have

```
{ _attributes: { name: 'titolo', description: 'il titolo della sezione' },
  field:
   [ { _attributes:
        { name: 'titolo',
          type: 'input',
          label: 'titolo',
          value: 'titolo' } },
     { _attributes:
        { name: 'colore',
          type: 'input',
          select: 'giallo,blu',
          label: 'seleziona il colore',
          value: 'titolo' } }
    ] 
}
```

and this is what i'd like to have

```
{  name: 'titolo', description: 'il titolo della sezione' ,
  field:
   [ 
        { name: 'titolo',
          type: 'input',
          label: 'titolo',
          value: 'titolo' } ,

        { name: 'colore',
          type: 'input',
          select: 'giallo,blu',
          label: 'seleziona il colore',
          value: 'titolo' } 
    ] 
}
```

Basically removing the _attributes property, but maintaining its content.
I'd like to know if is there some smart method other than looping the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  _attributes: {
    name: 'titolo',
    description: 'il titolo della sezione'
  },
  field: [{
      _attributes: {
        name: 'titolo',
        type: 'input',
        label: 'titolo',
        value: 'titolo'
      }
    },
    {
      _attributes: {
        name: 'colore',
        type: 'input',
        select: 'giallo,blu',
        label: 'seleziona il colore',
        value: 'titolo'
      }
    }
  ]
}

obj = { ...obj._attributes, ...obj };
delete obj._attributes;
obj.field = obj.field.map(el => el._attributes);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks... it works like a charme. I was thinking of something like that but still i miss some shorthand ways of writing code...

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it with `reduce`:

```js
var obj={ _attributes: { name: 'titolo', description: 'il titolo della sezione' }, field: [ { _attributes: { name: 'titolo', type: 'input', label: 'titolo', value: 'titolo' } }, { _attributes: { name: 'colore', type: 'input', select: 'giallo,blu', label: 'seleziona il colore', value: 'titolo' } } ] };

var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,[k,v])=>{
  if(!Array.isArray(v)){
     acc = {...v, ...acc};
    } else {
     field = v.map(({_attributes})=>_attributes);
     acc = {...acc, field}
    }
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Technically this work through the entire object, and it works. I've got to understand everything that's written in it.....

Comment: @vitta nothing much to understand here just a trap of `spread operator`. :) and this approach won't mutate the existing object.